# cout not working before cin in visual studio community C++

Tags: c++, vs-community-edition

this code gives me error:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
    string name;
    cout << "enter your name: "<<endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << name << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

the error is:
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'c:\users\payman\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe'

but if I comment out first cout statement it works.
don't understand why.

Comment: I really really doubt that has anything to do with it. The error message ("cannot open file ...") suggests that the application was probably still running when you tried to recompile and link.

Comment: try to rename  the file `c:\users\payman\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe` and then try to build and run again.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is still running and so the file is locked. This has absolutely nothing to do with the code.